# Way to set all items to defaults of PyQt5 except labels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created a frame and added many pyqt5 items to that frame.

[image]

After adding the form, I want to clear all the items of the frame to default blank values. I can do that by setting individual items by .clear() method.

Is there any way where I can clear all the items in a frame or tab to clear(or default) values at one go?

Answer (score 2):

There is no method that cleans all the inputs. A simple solution is to iterate over the widgets using the findChildren method:

```py
for widget in parent_widget.findChildren([QLineEdit, QComboBox]):
    if hasattr(widget, "clear") and callable(widget.clear):
        widget.clear()
```

or

```py
for widget in parent_widget.findChildren(QWidget):
    if not isinstance(widget, QLabel) and hasattr(widget, "clear") and callable(widget.clear):
        widget.clear()
```

Comment: What is parent_widget here? will it be the parent frame name?

Comment: @sam The parent_widget is the widget that contains all the widgets you want to clean, in your case it seems to be the "frame"

Comment: It doesn't work because it even clears all lables. All name labels also get blanked with this. I need only values to be blanked.